# HashMap.put() method on an HashMap created from a list (containing HashMap Objects ) modifies the original list Objects

Tags: java, hashmap

In my code I have an ArrayList **contentChecklist** which stores HashMap objects in it. After adding all the HashMap objects in the List, and if I get the last HashMap object from the list and store it in new HashMap object (**CheckListMaptemp**) and use  `CheckListMaptemp.put("place", "somePlace");` . It is modifying the original HashMap oject present in the List.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    List<HashMap> contentChecklist = new ArrayList<>();

    Map<String,String> checklIstMap1= new HashMap<>();
    checklIstMap1.put("name", "name1");
    checklIstMap1.put("uuid", "001");

    contentChecklist.add(checklIstMap1);

    Map<String,String>  checklIstMap2= new HashMap<>();
    checklIstMap2.put("name", "name2");
    checklIstMap2.put("uuid", "002");

    contentChecklist.add(checklIstMap2);

    Map<String,String> CheckListMaptemp= (Map<String, String>) contentChecklist.get(contentChecklist.size()-1);

    CheckListMaptemp.put("place", "somePlace");

    for (Iterator iterator = contentChecklist.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Map object = (Map) iterator.next(); 
        String val = (String) object.get("place");
        System.out.println(val);
    }
}
```

The output is :

null

#### somePlace

I know this is the correct behaviour , but I am eager to know how **contentChecklist** contents gets modified when we invoke  `CheckListMaptemp.put("place", "somePlace");` on **CheckListMaptemp** , even though both are different objects .

Comment: SideNote: please don't use rawtypes! See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it/2770692

Comment: I have added Generics , But it doesn't make any difference in output  right?

Comment: No, it does not change the behavior here. Just wanted to point this out in case you are not aware of this.

Comment: "even though both are different objects". They are *not* different objects. `Map.get` does not make new objects, it gives you (another reference to) the object from the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how Collection works. Whenever you added any object inside a collection, your collection just point to the same object. It won't creates new object.

In your case, you created two `HashMap` object `checklIstMap1` and `checklIstMap2`. When you added it in `ArrayList` i.e. `contentChecklist`, Your `ArrayList` just hold the reference of both the map. It won't creates new Map and added it in List.

So when you do 
`Map<String,String> CheckListMaptemp= (Map)contentChecklist.get(contentChecklist.size()-1);`.
It just returns the reference of the map object, It won't creates new Object and returns.

So if you will do any modification it will reflect in the same object.

Answer (score 2):

```
Map CheckListMaptemp= (Map)contentChecklist.get(contentChecklist.size()-1);
```

The variable `CheckListMaptemp` is a reference to the `Map` object contained in the list at position `contentChecklist.size()-1`. So, whatever changes you make using that reference will be reflected in that `Map` object. The reference DOES NOT point to another `Map` object.